# Setting one column value after another

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table where I want one value to be set to the same as another when inserting.

Here's the table in question;

```
CREATE TABLE categories (  
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  root INT NULL DEFAULT id,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I want the column ´root´ to get the same value as the ´id´ column gets when inserting a new row. I guess I can just do it in two queries, but I hoped I could do it in just one.

Thanks,
_L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use triggers. Do you use MySQL 5.0.2 or later? Because before that MySQL does not have triggers.

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER id_root_same AFTER INSERT ON categories 
FOR EACH ROW SET root = NEW.id;
```

But why would you do such a thing? It does not make sense.

Comment: I currently use 5.0.75, so I guess it should work.

I'll give it a go! :-)

Comment: I dropped this workaround and fixed the actual problem instead. Thanks for the help :-)